# conditional-middleware-in-aspnet-core is not working in asp.net core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I followed [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/conditional-middleware-in-aspnet-core) article to implement conditional middle-ware in our project and it was working perfectly fine. **But as we upgraded our project from .netcore 1.0 to .netcore 1.1, it is not working.**

I have written below code in my startup.

```
Func<HttpContext, bool> isApiRequest = (HttpContext context) => context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/api/");

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

//For MVC not API
app.UseWhen(context => !isApiRequest(context), appBuilder =>
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
        SignInScheme = "Cookies",
        AutomaticChallenge = true,


        Authority = authority,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        ClientId = "sampleClient",
        //ClientSecret = "secret",

        Scope = { "openid" , "profile" },

        ResponseType = "id_token token",//"code id_token",                        

        SaveTokens = true
    });
});

//FOR API
app.UseWhen(context => isApiRequest(context), appBuilder =>
{
    app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Authority = authority,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        AllowedScopes =
        {
            "scope1",
            "scope2"
        }
    });
});
```

Now when I try to access ActionMethod which is View based (means not starting with api), even in that condition api authentication work, not Cookie based authentication. And API based authentication works perfectly fine.

We are building our project on latest version of Identity Server 4.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `appBuilder` inside the conditional branch instead of `app`? Just a thought, it just looks odd.

Comment: It really is odd. Since the config function runs on startup, **it will** register all those middleware as if the condition never existed.

Comment: Just wanted to add I am having the same problem in VS2017 .net core 1.1. The given delegate never seems to be executed.

Answer (score 5):

Change both conditional blocks to use `appBuilder` not `app`.

The blog article is wrong. You are now registering them on the top-level middleware stack instead of the child builder.

So for example:

```
app.UseWhen(context => !isApiRequest(context), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true
            });

            appBuilder.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = "Cookies",
                AutomaticChallenge = true,


                Authority = authority,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                ClientId = "sampleClient",
                //ClientSecret = "secret",

                Scope = { "openid" , "profile" },

                ResponseType = "id_token token",//"code id_token",                        

                SaveTokens = true
            });
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Is some middleware still triggered though it should not be? Add breakpoints and see what is happening.

Comment: When I execute my action method from clicking in View, the breakpoint do hit in delegate with saying that action method is not starting with api, but further I am not able to debug it. And code do check in both of "UseWhen" condition.

Comment: Logs. idsrv was not authenticated.
The request path /Home/PlayerLogin does not match a supported file type
Authorization failed for user: (null).
uthorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'
AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was not authenticated